# Include CSS within WebView in Xamarin Forms with a Source URL (iOS & Android)

Tags: css, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I am trying to include some custom css within a webview on xamarin forms so the website being used can be customized with css styles, changing colors or other css style classes.

I have done this before using native code in Xcode and Android Studio, however this project is using xamarin forms and visual studio.

I believe what we need to do is include css within a custom webview renderer for android and ios. (would not be surprised if there was an easier way).

I have tried various methods being shown online and can not find a solution. Searching online there are some methods however they are not for xamarin forms.

Below is a snippet of my xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView" Source="https://odapps.org/" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Navigating="WebViewTesti_OnNavigating"/>
```

Another snippet of my xaml.cs:

```
public WebViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckConnectivity();
            WebView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;
        }
```

I am trying to have inline css styles load while using an external source url like google.com.

For those curious, this is how I have done it in xcode and android studio, but need it for Xamarin Forms:

Xcode:

```
ViewControllers file within xCode

let cssString = "*:not(input):not(textarea) { -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none; } footer{display:none;}"
```

Android Studio:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)

view.loadUrl("javascript: $('.footer,#sg-smartbanner').css('display','none')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Custom Renderer** and load the CSS style in iOS.

#### in iOS project

```
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(myWebRender))]

namespace xxx.iOS
{
    class myWebRender : WebViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                UIWebView myWebView = (UIWebView)this.NativeView;
               
            }
        }

        private void LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //. . .

          NSString jsStr= new NSString("xxx");
          webView.EvaluateJavascript(jsStr); 
        }
    }
}
```

And for Android , you just need to implement it in forms.

```
webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;

private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
   var webview = sender as WebView;

   var jsString = "$('.footer').css('display','none')";

   webview.Eval(jsString);
}
```

### Update

In android , webview will block JS event in default . So you can enable it by using **Custom Renderer**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {

                Android.Webkit.WebView webview =(Android.Webkit.WebView) Control;
                WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;


                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!! I will try it out today.

Curious for the following:

NSString jsStr= new NSString("xxx");
var jsString = "xxx";

The 'xxx' is where the css will be placed?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the css I would use if the primary style is: .branding { display: none; }. I am not able to get this to work on android. (I have not tested iOS yet).

Comment: I have updated the working methods for xcode and android studio. Unfortunately your solution has not been able to work for me.

Comment: Did you test it on android?

Comment: Yes I tested on android, however I think the cookies and cache needed to be cleared for me to see the effect take place...? I will try again this week.

Comment: As an update, the answer you have provided is correct and does allow for css to be added within the webview on both android and ios. However on iOS i did not use the custom view renderer and it worked as expected.

I am curious if there is a better way of doing this as the css only injects after the web page has fulling loaded.

There is a method for On_Navigating if maybe adding a delay to injecting the css for a few moments to allow the web page to start to load and include the css at the same time instead of after it has finished loading.